# SlackAPI - Trouble returning message with multiple variables

Tags: python, slack-api, openweathermap

I have the following code for my Slack bot:

```
    if command.startswith(COMMAND_FIVE):
        owm = pyowm.OWM()

        owm.set_API_key('')
        observation = owm.weather_at_id(4744326)
        w = observation.get_weather()
        jsondata= w.get_temperature('fahrenheit')
        RESPOND = ("The current temperature (Fahrenheit) is:",(jsondata["temp"]),"\nThe high is:",(jsondata["temp_max"]),"\nThe low is:",(jsondata["temp_min"]),"\n*Note: This can change*")
        response = (RESPOND)
        print("Someone got the weather.")

    # Sends the response back to the channel
    slack_client.api_call(
        "chat.postMessage",
        channel=channel,
        text=response or default_response
    )
```

When I call this command, I get the following back:

[image: What the slack bot returns.]
How can i format the message so it returns everything, not just the bottom line?

Comment: How are you talking to Slack? Are you using any libraries or sending direct calls to the API? Are you using a web framework? Please include that part of the code in your question.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I'm talking to it directly. I'm running my code from within VS Code.

Comment: OK but how exactly? How do you submit `response` to Slack? Are you making an API call or RTM or webhook or slash response, .... ??? Are you sending JSON or Plain text .... In short: please add your code.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken https://github.com/avrwhy/2022bot/blob/master/main.py

Comment: I added the missing piece to the full picture to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code that does not produce the expected result, is that you are passing your text as a tuple of strings to the API method. Apparently the API method is reducing that internally to just one element (the last).

To make this work you want to pass your text as one complete string to the API method's text property.

Here is a new version of your code that should work better:

```
RESPOND = [
    "The current temperature (Fahrenheit) is: {0:.2f}".format(jsondata["temp"]),
    "The high is: {0:.2f}".format(jsondata["temp_max"]),
    "The low is: {0:.2f}".format(jsondata["temp_min"]),
    "*Note: This can change*"]
response = "\n".join(RESPOND)
```